# Check if a subset of points from a cluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a set of items with each represented by an embedding in high dimension. I want to see if a subset of these points form a 'cluster'(word used in loose sense to mean if the items are more similar to each other as compared to others).

I have tried to project and plot in low dimension using PCA or t-SNE, but I don't get a very clear picture from that.

Is there some python module which given the subset calculates the 'cohesiveness' in the subset vis-a-vis the entire set?

Comment: isn't the variance of your points a good measure for (anti-)cohesiveness?

Comment: variance will tell you about the closeness of the subset points, the metric I want should ideally also include the 'farness' from other points as well. i.e, the points are closely held away from the other points.